# General Tag Classification: Categorizing the Madness

Tags: discussion

There are currently 216 tags on The Workplace. We can clean up a lot of the tags, and retag a lot more, but as long as users [only need 150 reputation to create new tags](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) it is just going to happen again and again.

I would like to discuss a general categorizing of tags in to grand categories to make it much easier to find similar questions in the right sidebar, and to help people posting questions find similar questions to reduce duplicates.

## Proposal

Questions on this site are broadly categorized in to these categories:

1. Questions about getting a job
2. Questions about leaving a job (voluntarily or otherwise)
3. Questions about issues with the current job

Within each of these overarching categories there will be a lot of sub-categories, but in general questions should rarely (if ever) overlap. Each one of these questions could have relevant sub-tags. For instance:

1. Questions about getting a job/hiring for a job

   - resume/cv/cover letter
   - interviews
   - negotiation
   - networking
   - hiring
2. Questions about leaving a job/letting someone go

   - 'restructuring'
   - mergers & acquisitions
   - exit interviews
   - remaining vacation days
   - severance
   - recommendations
3. Questions about a current job

   - management
   - corporate culture
   - raises
   - promotions
   - learning/education

<sup>(the above list is obviously not exhaustive)</sup>

## Reasoning

Tags are used to find similar questions. Unfortunately, [cover-letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cover-letter) may not find a question tagged [resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) By putting both these questions under the umbrella of [finding-employment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finding-employment) or something similar, we would be sure that even if a past question was tagged as [resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) with a very similar question, posting a question tagged [cover-letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cover-letter) would have a better chance of created 'related questions' showing the similar thread. This would assist with finding duplicates, giving new users more reference points to look at, etc.

It would also make the process of categorizing existing posts much easier. We could go through the major tags, and automatically add a single tag based on which category that tag fits in. This would allow us to more quickly weed through the questions and create a more accessible knowledge base based on which part of the employment process people are looking for answers about.

This would also allow us to make very helpful wikis, since each tag could be associated with a category, and the tag wiki for each of these could include the major sub-tags associated. This would allow people to tag with [interviewing](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interviewing) for instance, and automatically have [finding-employment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finding-employment) pop up as a suggestion.

## Discussion

Are there any situations where one of these three tags will absolutely not apply? Should there be other tags included, or a slightly more broken down structure? Is the concept of having required tags unecessarily pigeon-holing potential users rather than making the site/answers more accessible?

Comment: This, definately this, if there is anything i have seen whilst going through all the tags its that a cleanup could increase the ease at which people find questions and decrease the confusion over what tags to use, which should stop the wanton creation of whatever happens to apply