# Can we make our help page on tags more relevant to our site?

Tags: discussion, tags, help-center

We have had a bit of a problem with tags for a while. There were some steps taken in that direction about 4 years ago ([RhysW's Tag Reviews - Suggested Course of action](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2005/3192), [The Workplace Tag List Project](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1943/3192), [General Tag Classification: Categorizing the Madness](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2009/3192), [Another tag discussion!](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2783/3192), and many more). 
However, a lot still remains to be done, and this has been discussed a couple of times more recently ([Our tags are kind of a mess.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5006/3192), [2018 moderator election question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5189/3192)).

As a first step in our new round of efforts, can we update the boilerplate in the [help page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) and make it more relevant to our site?

Examples listed further below make less sense here (and also feed in to [a certain](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5195/3192)   [other problem](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5188/3192)). These examples are the first thing that caught my attention, but I am not suggesting that we *only* replace these examples. We can also review if we want to update some of the other text on that page to be more consistent with our policies.

What are your thoughts on this?

---

> create compound tags using hyphens rather than spaces (like [visual-studio]) rather than multiple tags separated by spaces ([visual] [studio])

> Replace spaces with hyphens (-) to combine multiple words into a single word (e.g., tag "unit testing" as unit-testing)

> For example, [css] is probably more appropriate than [cascading-style-sheets]

> Can I use jQuery to foo the bar on the baz, or am I stuck using plain JavaScript?

Comment: I think making the examples TWP-specific would be a great idea... will work on some phrasings when I get some time

Comment: So... any updates on this? Seems that the post didn't get much attention, nor did the wording I suggested (except for IDrink's edit)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the phrasings I propose. Perhaps we can tune these out first, include the changes, and then proceed to discuss if we would want to edit other parts as well:

> create compound tags using hyphens rather than spaces (like [company-culture]) rather than multiple tags separated by spaces ([company] [culture])

> Replace spaces with hyphens (-) to combine multiple words into a single word (e.g., tag "work environment" as [work-environment])

> For example, [ceo] is probably more appropriate than [chief-executive-officer]

> For example, rather than writing, "Communication, Coworker: How do I remind him to follow up on my emails?" – which forces tags into the title – you can convey the same information in a conversational tone:
>
> ```
> How can I politely communicate to my coworker to remember to follow up on my emails?
> ```